# Finding collisions of polynomial rolling hashes

Tags: hash, cryptanalysis, collision-resistance, finite-field, group-theory

A [polynomial hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash#Polynomial_rolling_hash) defines a hash as $H = c_1a^{k-1} + c_2a^{k-2} ... + c_ka^0$, all modulo $2^n$ (that is, in $GF(2^n)$).

For brevity, let $c$ be a $k$ dimensional vector (encapsulating all the individual $c_n$ values).

Are there particular values for $c$ that make the probability of collisions between two randomly chosen $a$ greater than $k/2^n$?

I would argue that there are not.  For $H(c, a)$ equals evaluating a polynomial (of degree at most $k$) at $a$.  Thus, $H_c(x)$ defines a polynomial with degree at most $k$.  Let $H_{c,a}(x) = H_c(x) - H_c(a)$; the zeroes of $H_{c,a}$ are precisely the points where $H_c(x) = H_c(a)$, and there can be no more than $k$ such zeroes.  Thus, for any non-zero $c$, two randomly chosen $a,a'$ have $H(a) = H(a')$ with probability $\le k/2^n $.

However, [this crypto CTF challenge](https://github.com/utcoalition/utcctf-19/blob/master/crypto-random-hash/server.py) seems to argue certain $c$ do produce collisions, and [this solution explains](https://buaq.net/go-38277.html#Crypto-Random-Hash) and demonstrates it (unfortunately most of the explanation is in Chinese).  **Where is my mistake?**

Comment: Modulo $2^n$ is operations in the ring $\mathbb{Z}_{2^n}$ which is NOT the same as $GF(2^n)$.

Answer (score 2):

This ring has zero divisors so the answer is different than over fields.

Let $H(a)-H(a')=c_1 a^{k-1}+c_2 a^{k-2}+\cdots+c_k,$ and let $j$ be the largest nonnegative integer such that $2^j$ divides $gcd(c_1,\ldots,c_k).$

**Claim:** Let $j$ be as above, then the polynomial $H(a)-H(a')$ can have $k\times 2^{j}$ roots, leading to a collision probability of $$\frac{k}{2^{n-j}}.$$

*Proof:* If the coefficients of the difference polynomial have a gcd divisible by $2^j$ then all values of the polynomial are in the subset (which is an ideal)
$$2^j \mathbb{Z}_{2^n}=\{2^j u: u \in \mathbb{Z}_{2^n}\}.$$ This means that the difference polynomial is of the form $2^j g(a)$ for some polynomial with gcd equal to 1. Therefore, it is enough for $g(a)$ to take values in $2^{n-j}\mathbb{Z}_{2^n}$ for $2^j g(a)$ to take on the value zero. This means that each zero of $g(a)$ is duplicated $2^j$ times to be a zero of the difference polynomial so the probability that the difference polynomial takes on the value zero is now
$$
\frac{k 2^j}{2^n}=\frac{k}{2^{n-j}}.
$$

*Example* from [Magma Calculator][1] of a degree $k=2$ polynomial, which has 2 roots and one where $j=2,$ which has $k 2^j=8$ roots.

code:

```
Z2to6:=IntegerRing(2^6); Z2to6;
R<a>:=PolynomialRing(Z2to6); R;
{* Z2to6!(a^2+63*a): a in Z2to6 *};
{* Z2to6!(4*(a^2+63*a)): a in Z2to6 *};}
```

output:

````
Univariate Polynomial Ring in a over IntegerRing(64)
{* 0^^2, 2^^2, 4^^2, 6^^2, 8^^2, 10^^2, 12^^2, 14^^2, 16^^2, 18^^2, 20^^2,
22^^2, 24^^2, 26^^2, 28^^2, 30^^2, 32^^2, 34^^2, 36^^2, 38^^2, 40^^2, 42^^2,
44^^2, 46^^2, 48^^2, 50^^2, 52^^2, 54^^2, 56^^2, 58^^2, 60^^2, 62^^2 *}`
{* 0^^8, 8^^8, 16^^8, 24^^8, 32^^8, 40^^8, 48^^8, 56^^8 *}```

The second polynomial $4(a^2+63a)$ has a gcd of 4 thus it has 8 roots not 2.

The magma list notation 0^^8 means the element 0 appears 8 times in the list.




  [1]: http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/
````

Comment: Fascinating.  Can you explain the math a bit more.  It seems my mistake was confusing the Zn ring for the GF field, and, since the Zn ring has zero divisors, polynomials can have greater degree than I expected.  Your equations remind me of gcd / Euclidean algorithm, but it would be very helpful if you could elaborate.